# CSS Animation: how can I set the speed in X direction while still following an offset path?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm making a graph where I plot a curve.  The curve can change daily, but the X-axis is always a 24-hour timeline.  I want to animate a current time indicator along the curve, and I'm trying to do it purely in CSS if possible.  This means I want the speed of the animation to be linear in the X direction, not along a percentage of the path.

If I use percentage,

```
@keyframes followpath {
    to {
        offset-distance: 100%;
    }
}
```

the timing is off because the path gets longer for time periods where the curve is steeper, and shorter for time periods where the curve is less steep.

If I use translateX,

```
@keyframes followpath {
    from {
        transform: translateX( 0% );
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX( 100% );
    }
}
```

the timing is correct, but there's no way to follow the path.  Is there any way to set the speed to be linear in the X direction while still following the path?

If it's not possible, I imaging I will have to use Pythagoras to get the length of the translation relative to the X distance I want to move, but this would significantly increase the calculations required, so it would be nice to stick to CSS.

Comment: Could you show us an example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Would it be easier just to draw the graph and gradually reveal it by shrinking an element that lies in top of it?